# Creating a Rails partial that is model-agnostic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the two Ruby on Rails models `SafetyTest` and `TeamDue`, and want to create a partial called `_seasonal.html.erb` that can work with either models.

The real problem is adding a link to create a new instance. For example, it would be this code for *just* `SafetyTest`:

```
<%= link_to new_safety_test_path %>
```

Now I want to be able to specify in my view, when I'm rendering `_seasonal.html.erb`, whether I want such a link for `SafetyTest` *or* `TeamDue` . I'm not sure what local to pass to this partial so that it creates the right `new` link without making a mess.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Polymorphic URL helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html).

Comment: This gets close to the solution, but let's assume that I won't have an existing instance to pass to `polymorphic_url`. How should I give the information to the partial?

Comment: Is a symbol the best solution, perhaps? So `:safety_test` and `:team_due`?

Comment: Yes, I would go with symbol or with direct class reference (new_polymorphic_path(SafetyTest)).

Comment: Thanks! I'm also having trouble figuring out how to pass a GET parameter to this. Say that I have `student_id: student_id` as a parameter. Where in `polymorphic_path(symbol)` do I put that?

Comment: You mean a query string? polymorphic_path(symbol, student_id: 42)