# Creating a Rails partial that is resource-agnostic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This question is related to my previous question, [Creating a Rails partial that is model-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14075790/805556).

I am trying to create a Rails partial that is given a variable, say, `seasonal_type`, and does several different operations, such as querying a resource, and accessing instance variables, based on the value of the variable.

To be more concrete: I have the two models `SafetyTest` and `TeamDue`, which belong to `Student`. In one particular case in this partial, I need to call either 
`@student.safety_tests` or `@student.team_dues`. I would like to pass the variable `seasonal_type` to the partial and like that determine which of the two is executed. How would I be able to do this? The value of the variable could be whatever is most convenient, such as a symbol (`:safety_test`) or a model (`SafetyTest`).

There is also another part to this question. In my controller, I precaculcated some instance variables for `SafetyTest` and `TeamDue`, such as `@valid_safety_test` and `@valid_team_due`. In my partial, how can I use *either* of these two instance variables, based on the value of `seasonal_type`? Or should I just calculate these values inside the partial, even though that would be against the MVC structure?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

In my controller, I created an array with the models of both seasonal types: `[SafetyTest, TeamDue]`

Then I iterated over this array, and used the model to query all the information that I needed from the database. I put that information into an array and passed it on to the view with an instance variable. So this array also has two items, one for `SafetyTest` and one for `TeamDue`.

Then the partial  iterates through *this* array and renders the view necessary.